Unable to start Appium inspector after restarting my mac
I have been using Appium (v2.5.4) inspector as normally and everything works fine however I have to restart my machine and now I am getting the message:
Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported. Read https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables for more details
Using uiautomator2@3.5.0. Has anyone come across this issue before?
I have looked at my env variables they all look good. I have closed appium, android studio and restarted. However its still not working.

macOS, Windows or Linux?

macOS with M1 silicone chip.

how about re-installing Appium ?

Can you show us your environment vars?

To ensure that all Appium dependencies are correctly installed and configured, you can use the appium-doctor tool. This utility helps diagnose and fix common issues with your Appium setup.
